# Stroud freezes right before Western Approach during the Venatori Battle

Tags: technical-issues, dragon-age-inquisition

So I'm going through my third playthrough, and I've come across a problem which is really ruining the experience.

Basically, the main storyline right before you battle the Venatori for the first time in the Western Approach. Right before the scene begins, there is a cutscene where Hawke and Stroud are present, and conversing. After Stroud's initial response, the game freezes somewhat. As in, the animations of the world are still active, the sands are sweeping the characters are swaying. It's not completely frozen but it's enough to stop the game entirely.

I've tried to skip the dialogue by holding Square - doesn't work. I've restarted my console several times, as well as deleting that auto-save section and replaying it. Any solutions?

Comment: What platform are you playing on?

Comment: PS3. I know, bad choice but I have played two other non-freezing playthroughs on the same console.

Comment: If it is about Dragon age inquisition, add the tag to the question and remove it from the title. Would do it but I don't play the game to be sure you're talking about it.

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to add custom tags.